# Highcharts stock chart X axis date issue

Tags: r, highcharts

I'm trying to build a simple stock chart in R, but for some reason the dates on the X axis are not converted in a proper format:

[image]

I've tried all sorts of functions to convert my dates (as.Date, as.POSIXct,...), but nothing seems to help.

This is my code to render the chart:

```
    highchart(type = "stock") %>%
      hc_add_series(name = "Price", type = "line", color = "blue", data = df$price) %>%
      hc_xAxis(categories = df$timestamp, type = "date")
```

My input data frame has just 2 columns: timestamp & price.

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Simon

Comment: It looks like your data is not being interpreted correctly.
Could you please add a sample of this data so that I can also test it?
You can also do this in vanilla JS. Here you can find a basic template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xrgykeou/

Answer (score 0):

In the series, add this
"tooltip" : {
"custom" : true
},

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Any idea how this would look like in R code? KR, Simon